# What is the difference between grain boundaries and dislocations?

Tags: material-science, metals, lattice-model

Specifically I'm interested in how the difference relates to plastic deformation.

---

To my understanding, a dislocation is a non-uniform part of the crystal lattice (basically where the crystal isn't perfect) which strains the nearby bonds. Because the bonds are already stressed it is easier for them to break. So fracture happens along the lines of non-uniformities, the dislocations.

To strengthen the material you create plastic deformation. This forces the line of strained bonds, the dislocations, to get tangled up so they end at areas of solid crystal lattice instead of running through the whole material. If the dislocations were long the material could break along them. Plastic deformation makes the dislocations short and varied in direction.

Let me know if I have anything wrong.

---

Grain boundaries, on the other hand, are areas where the growing crystal lattice stopped or met another growing crystal lattice. Here is where my confusion begins.

To me a grain boundary would be similar to a dislocation. It is an imperfect part of the crystal pattern. This imperfection would put strains on the bonds just like a dislocation. So then are the rules for fracture and strength the same for dislocations and grain boundaries? Are long areas of grain boundaries prone to fracture, like dislocations? Does plastic deformation scramble up these boundaries so they don't run long? Is the only difference between the two then in origin, and not mechanical properties?

Answer (score 3):

A dislocation is a more specific kind of crystal defect than what you describe. A dislocation is always of codimension 2. (That is, in a 2-D material, it is "0-dimensional", in a 3-D material it is "1-dimensional").

To explain more clearly what this means, in a 2-D material, a dislocation is "0-dimensional", that is, the primary straining happens only in the neighborhood of a point, as can be seen from the classic picture of a dislocation:

[image: dislocation]

Moreover, dislocations are characterized by having nonzero [Burgers vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_vector).

A grain boundary, by contrast, is a defect of codimension 1. Grain boundaries occur along surfaces in 3-D, lines in 2-D.

Comment: Great, thanks. So both put strain on the surrounding bonds. Then are the general rules for fracture and strength I described above true for both?